# Power BI pivot column with no aggregation errors

Tags: powerbi

I have a simple table that I want to pivot by the 'COLUMN_NAME' column:

[image]

When I pivot and aggregate by count it works fine:

[image]

When I try to pivot without aggregation, it gives this error:

[image]

> Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the enumeration to
> complete the operation. Details:
> [List]

Here is what I expected to happen:

[image]

thx in adavnce

Comment: You can refer solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218421/convert-data-in-table-from-row-to-column-in-powerbi/69219687?noredirect=1#comment122350728_69219687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pivot against a specific column, otherwise the powerbi engine can't determine how to keep the data in rows consistently.

Your input needs to be in a format similar to this:

| RecordID | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRODUCT_SUB_FAMILY | MYPRODUCT |
| 1 | MFG_STEP_NAME | FT1 |
| 1 | QTY_IN | 678 |
| 1 | QTY_OUT | 480 |
| 1 | AGG_YIELD | 0.70796 |
| 2 | PRODUCT_SUB_FAMILY | MYPRODUCT |
| 2 | MFG_STEP_NAME | SLT1 |
| 2 | QTY_IN | 66 |
| 2 | QTY_OUT | 0 |
| 2 | AGG_YIELD | 0 |

And then when you pivot, you select the RecordID as the column you pivot against.